# Excel nested if condition

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, excel-2010

I'm trying to write nested if condition using AND, OR, MIN, MAX inside IF condition. but i couldn't solve this below problem.

I have a column with Payments, if that payment is less then 20k then it should take 100% of the payment.

If the payment is between 20k - 40k then need to calculate 80% of the payment but after calculating 80% the result is less then 20k then it should write 20k. if the result is more then it should write the result.

if the payment is between 40k - 75k then need to calculate 70% of the payment but after calculating 70% the result is less then 40k then it should write 40k. if the result is more then it should write the result.

if the payment is between 75k - 100k then need to calculate 60% of the payment but after calculating 60% the result is less then 75k then it should write 75k. if the result is more then it should write the result.

if the payment is greater then 100k need to calculate 50% of the payment but after calculating 50% the result is less then 100k then it should write 100k. if the result is more then it should write the result.

I tried writing nested if condition to form one formula using min function and AND operator but nothing is giving the result accurately.

I have tried:

```
=IF(B8<=20000,B8,IF(AND(B8>=20001,B8*80%<20000),20000,B8*80%),IF(AND(B8>=40001,B8*70%<40000),40000,B8*70%),IF(AND(B8>=75001,B8*60%<75000),75000,B8*60%),IF(AND(B8>=100001,B8*50%<100000),100000,B8*50%)
```

but it throws the error `called too many arguments`.

Comment: Perhaps you can show us the formula that you attempted to use. We could help to debug it.

Comment: =IF(B8<=20000,B8,IF(AND(B8>=20001,B8*80%<20000),20000,B8*80%),IF(AND(B8>=40001,B8*70%<40000),40000,B8*70%),IF(AND(B8>=75001,B8*60%<75000),75000,B8*60%),IF(AND(B8>=100001,B8*50%<100000),100000,B8*50%) throwing an error called too many aruuguments

Comment: You do have some improper nesting. `IF(AND(B8>=40001` is in the position of the 4th argument of the overall `IF` -- but `IF` doesn't take a fourth argument.

Comment: Can i get a small snipet of the first case so that i can re-write the remaining part of the formula.

Comment: I'm suspicious of your logic:  `60% of 75-100k` will **ALWAYS** be less than 75K. Perhaps if you showed a screenshot of a variety of inputs, with desired output, you question would be more clear.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Good catch. I implemented their description rather literally but didn't notice that bit.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
=IF(B8 <= 20000,B8,IF(B8 <= 40000,MAX(20000,0.8*B8),IF(B8 <= 75000,MAX(40000,0.7*B8),IF(B8 <= 100000,MAX(75000,0.6*B8),MAX(100000,0.5*B8)))))
```

I actually first wrote it in Notepad like this:

```
if(B8 <= 20000,
  B8,
  if(B8 <= 40000,
    max(20000,0.8*B8),
    if(B8 <= 75000,
      max(40000,0.7*B8),
      if(B8 <= 100000,
        max(75000,0.6*B8),
        max(100000,0.5*B8)
      )
    )
  )
)
```

since laying it out like that was the only way I could keep the logic straight.

A key point is that you only test if `B8 <= 40000` in a context in which you know that `B8 <= 20000` is false, so you don't need to test if you also have `B8 > 20000`. At that stage it is automatic.

Answer (score 0):

try this, here F2 is the cell with amonut you input

```
=MAX(LOOKUP((1-LOOKUP(F2,{0,20000,40000,75000,100000},{1,0.8,0.7,0.6,0.5}))*F2,{0,20000,40000,75000,100000},{20000,40000,75000,100000,0}),(1-LOOKUP(F2,{0,20000,40000,75000,100000},{1,0.8,0.7,0.6,0.5}))*F2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this formula. C2 is the cell with the payment amount in it.

`=MIN(C2,C2*INDEX({1,0.8,0.7,0.6,0.5},MATCH(C2/1000,{0,20,40,75,100},1)))`

The advantage of using INDEX/MATCH is that it isn't volatile.